# Hide labels in narrow areas of stacked area chart (D3 Observable)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, label, observablehq

I am working on a 100% stacked area chart in Observable with labels for each series, but I have a ton of series and would like to hide the labels for series that are too small to display (currently they are all scrunched on top of each other). Is anyone able to advise on how I can do this?

I created an if else statement and know I need to somehow say that if the value is below a certain share of the total, don’t display the label, but I am struggling to figure out what exactly needs to go in that statement. If anyone is able to advise, that would be extremely helpful!

Current notebook: https://observablehq.com/d/b981c470fa4ebddc

Comment: Your intension is to hide a label if you find another one that overlaps it?

Answer (score 1):

You can pre-compute the overall average for each country - see the mock example below:

```js
// mock up of your data, countries are a, b, c etc
const data = [
  {year: 2020, a: 1, b: 4, c: 3},
  {year: 2021, a: 6, b: 5, c: 9},
  {year: 2022, a: 4, b: 8, c: 9},
  {year: 2023, a: 8, b: 1, c: 7},
  {year: 2024, a: 2, b: 5, c: 6},
  {year: 2025, a: 7, b: 2, c: 9}
]

// threshold beneath which hide the label
const threshold = 0.27;

// countries from first data item
const countries = Object.keys(data[0]).filter(k => k != "year");

// return an object of country totals
const averages = countries.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const sum = data.reduce((sum, obj) => sum + obj[curr], 0);
  acc.push({country: curr, sum: sum});
  return acc;
}, []); 

// get grand total for each country
const grandTotal = averages.reduce((sum, obj) => sum + obj.sum, 0);

// calculate average and show flag
averages.forEach(obj => {
  let avg = obj.sum / grandTotal;
  obj.avg = avg;
  obj.show = avg >= threshold;
});

console.log(averages);
```

You can then append the `show` property to your `series` object in the noteboook e.g.

```
series.forEach(obj => obj.show = averages.find(avg => avg.country === series.key).show)
```

Then in your label rendering section:

```
.text((d, i) => d.show ? d.key : "")
```